# How to clear session on Custom HandleError Attribute in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating my own custom HandleError attribute on MVC.

```
public class MVCError : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
         //Supposed to remove session here
    }
}
```

But it seems that I cannot use the Session to remove specific session on my website. Is this possible? Or do I need to clear my session on Global.asax file:

```
    protected void Application_Error()
    {
        Session.Remove("Check");
        Debug.WriteLine("An error has occurred.");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear use `HttpContext.Current` object `HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove("Check");`

```
public class MVCError : HandleErrorAttribute
    {
        public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
             //Supposed to remove session here
             HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove("Check");
        }
    }
```